# change other element in array with the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <el-row>
    <el-col :span="24">
      <el-image
        v-for="(card, index) in randomCards"
        :key="card.indexOf"
        :src="card.url"
        :id="(card.id = index)"
        fit="fill"
        @click="flipCards(index)"
      ></el-image>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCardsId: [],
      randomCards: null,
      data: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    getResults() {
      axios
        .get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search", {
          params: { limit: 36 },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.randomCards = response.data
            .concat(response.data)
            .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
        });
    },
    flipCards(cardIndex) {
      this.randomCards[cardIndex].url = "1";
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getResults();
  },
};
</script>
```

When I load the page and click the image, I see changes in two elements in the array because they have the same value but a different index. I think that's because I pushed the  same  array. I also tried `Array.from()` and the  spread operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `response.data.concat(response.data)`, you're appending the original objects   *by reference*, so changes to one instance affect the other as they refer to the same data.

Assuming the data items are all shallow, a quick way to clone the data is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them into new objects:

```js
this.randomCards = response.data.concat(response.data.map(x => ({ ...x })))
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cloning-object-f2l9p?file=/src/App.vue:563-619)